# Is there any problem installing Linux to an SD card?

Tags: partition, system-installation, performance, sd-card

I have a laptop that comes with an SD card slot (large size) and it is possible to boot from there. If I installed Debian such that the OS partitions are on a 128 GB SD card and /home/ is on an SSD, would that cause any performance issues or other problems? Is there any quality of SD cards that makes it a poor choice for installing the base OS there?

Answer (score 4):

You could of course install Linux to an SD card, as many Raspberry Pi users do, but this is generally not a good idea for longterm casual use because of those wearing out faster than SSDs or HDDs.

You might want to look [there](https://superuser.com/questions/17350/whats-the-life-expectancy-of-an-sd-card) for further details. As you'll see, your mileage may vary, but all flash memory will wear out some day.

A wear-free usage would be never writing to the SD after the initial installation (except for system upgrades and such), which may be useful for small projects, but might not suit your particular needs. Nevertheless, you can look [there](https://github.com/nils-werner/raspi-overlayroot) to get an idea of how it's done.